# google map api key not working, need a defferent key

Tags: google-maps

sorry, I know this question might be too common, but I really couldn't figure out why the google map on my site is not working, I did following what the documentation told me to do, I sign up a google map api key, and I implement the follwoing code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps?   file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=mykey">
    </script>
```

I did replace mykey with the google map key for the url I entered during sign up, but when I go to my website, there still show me a alert saying that the site need a different google map api key, I wonder this could be other reasons but I can't think any, anyone could help me with that, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use google maps v3, you only need a key for maps v2:

```
How does the Google Maps APIs key system work?

Note: Google Maps API keys are only required when using the JavaScript Maps API V2 and the Maps API for Flash.
```

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem

Comment: I go to this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html to get the key, is it correct?

Comment: V3 now uses keys as part of the new limits that have been put in place.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you sign up for your key? The Maps API now uses keys that are generated through the API console: https://code.google.com/apis/console so you can go there and generate a new key.

Comment: I go to this code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html to get the key, is it correct?

Comment: You don't have to enable billing if you don't want to. You only need to if you plan on using more than 25K map views a day